# Saving user data from Spotify API

Tags: spotify

I'm currently toying around with the Spotify api to create a mobile app that "matches" people based on their top artists, tracks, and genres.

For this, I need to save the user data (top 50 tracks and artists, from the Personalization API) and fetch them back as needed.

So basically if **User A** signed in the app with its Spotify account, its data is saved in my DB.

After that, if **User B** wants to see if he is a match with **User A** the server will provide information about both **User A** and **User B**, for instance, what artist they both like.

There is this point in the TOS about user data:

*"Spotify user data can be cached only for operating your SDA. If a Spotify user logs out of your SDA or becomes inactive, you will delete any Spotify Content related to that user stored on your servers. To be clear, you are not permitted to store Spotify Content related to a Spotify user or otherwise request user data if a Spotify user is not using your SDA"*

As far as I understand, it's ok to save the user data in an external server/DB as long as I delete that data as soon as the user logs out from my app, is that right?

I'm asking because at the same time there is this restriction stated in the TOS:

*"Do not transfer Spotify Content to unauthorized third parties, including (i) directly or indirectly transferring any data (including aggregate, anonymous or derivative data) received from Spotify to, or use such data in connection with, any ad network, ad exchange, data broker, or other advertising or monetization-related toolset, even if a user consents to such transfer or use; or (ii) to another music service that competes with Spotify or the Spotify Service."*

Comment: This sounds like it would be a good question for the Spotify forum https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/bd-p/Spotify_Developer, however, when I was building my app https://traklist.net/ which also analyzes top artists users data from multiple users to create a common playlist I cached that content with a time to live. Based on their definition I should be in compliance because data "can be cached for operating [my] SDA" but I did not transfer that content to any third parties.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware they had a forum. I've also posted the question there. I'll be sure to update my question here in case I get an answer.